# Can NuGet package sources be exported as settings from Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I want to export the sources I have listed here and import them to a new installation of VS 2017.

[image: VS_2017 NuGet Settings]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data are stored in a file call [NuGet.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses) under `%AppData%\NuGet\`. Backup this file and restore it to the same location on the new system.